# Executing "echo $PATH" from a c program?

Tags: c, linux, path, exec

I am trying to display, set & modify PATH environment variable from a C program. I am doing something like this:-

```
char *cmd[] = { "echo", "$PATH", (char *)0 };
if (execlp("echo", *cmd) == -1)
```

But I am not getting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display `$PATH`, try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

printf("PATH: %s\n",getenv("PATH"));
```

if you want to modify it, use `setenv()` or `putenv()`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `getenv()`, there's no need to go through a shell:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("PATH='%s'\n", getenv("PATH"));

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But you *won't* be able to *change* the value. Environment variables are inherited into child processes, but the child has its own copy. You can't change the shell's environment from a different program, regardless in which language it's written. You can of course change your own process' value, but that's not what you asked to do.

In the shell itself, you can change its current environment settings, but only there. This is why you need to use "source" to run shells scripts that change the environment.

Comment: You're fast. I'll add that you can type `man getenv` for the quite informative manual page.

Comment: Thanks. The thing that slows me down the most is the curious inability to type backslashes in the markdown editor. :)

Comment: unwind, I had never had troubles with backslashes... But that must have been the cause why you have no closing single quote in your string ;-)

Comment: @hacker: Thanks, fixed. Whenever I press backslash in the answer-editor, it gets immediately replaced by `enter code here`, with the text part selected so the next keypress replaces it.

Comment: unwind. Weird. Never happened to me (yet).

Comment: @hacker: This is increasingly off-topic, but I took it to meta.stackoverflow.com, and it seems to be a bug in the editor component.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
char *cmd[] = { "$PATH", (char *)0 };
if (execlp("echo", cmd) == -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

...

char *pPath;
pPath = getenv("PATH");
if (pPath!=NULL)
    printf ("The current path is: %s",pPath);
putenv("PATH=somepath");

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Better solutions already given, but by way of explanation; the $PATH variable is parsed and translated by the command shell, not the echo command itself. The solutions already suggested use getenv() to obtain the environment variable's value instead.

To invoke the command shell to perform this:

```
system( "echo $PATH" ) ;
```

but that solution is somewhat heavyweight since it invokes a new process and the entire command processor just to do that.